# Deploy JS from folder versus deploy from branch

Tags: git, azure, visual-studio-code, deployment, azure-appservice

The typical dev work flow seems to be, when using git or CICD, to deploy from **branch**. If I have multiple self-contained projects in sibling folders, and want to deploy from a folder, is there a way to *convert* the folder to a branch or is there a way in git or GitHub actions to deploy from a folder?

In VSCode, to Azure App Service using an extension, I can deploy the folder. In Azure portal, with local git, or actions/pipelines/CICD, I can deploy from branch.

Comment: What you can use to deploy will depend on the deployment system: Git isn't a deployment system. The reason things that start *with* Git generally use branch names, though, is simple enough: Git doesn't store *folders* in the first place. Git stores *commits*. You name a commit by raw hash ID. Nobody *wants* to use a hash ID though, so Git lets you use a branch name (meaning "the latest hash ID") or a tag name (meaning "an exact hash ID, never changing, but with a name instead of random gobbledygook"). The commit then has files, which your OS folder-izes (Git only has the files).

Comment: If you have a folder full of files, and want to turn that into a commit, you'd check out or create a branch name, remove *everything*, then create the right files and `git add` them and `git commit` to get a commit that contains exactly those files. Then you give this commit a name (branch or tag name) or rely on the fact that, because you're using some particular branch name, that name now means "the latest commit" which is the one you just made. Now you have a name for a commit that contains only those files. (Each commit acts as a full snapshot of all files, like a tar or winzip archive.)

Comment: Hi @torek - thanks for you comments - I know how git works. I'm asking for something beyond the basics, diving into deployment systems that aren't branch based.